Slow mode wait time - how to get it?
I have the following problem.
I have some code which uses pyrogram to periodically send a message into a few telegram supergroups that I moderate. Some of these groups have slow mode enabled. Some with 15 minutes wait, others with 60 minutes.
In the telegram app, when I send a message into a supergroup which has the slow mode enabled, it shows a little timer counting down the time until it is allowed to send the next message.
Within pyrogram, one can check by evaluating slowmode_enabled if a supergroup generally uses the slow mode. But is there some possibility to get the time one has to wait until the next message, just as in the telegram app?
I observed that when my code violates the wait time enforced by slow mode, it yields
Telegram says: [420 SLOWMODE_WAIT_X] (caused by "messages.ForwardMessages")
Pyrogram 2.3.43 thinks: A wait of 2605 seconds is required to send messages in this chat

Pls help I really don't know how to approach this :(

You can get the slow_mode_delay for the chat, keep track of when you sent the message, and wait until you can send another message. This is likely how Telegram clients handle it too. I don't use pyrogram, but the process should be simple.

You can handle this in two different ways.

Get to know the slow mode time from the ChatFull
Or handle the SlowmodeWait error with a try-except


Solution 1

# Set your chat_id and resolve the chat
chat_id = -100123456
peer = await app.resolve_peer(chat_id)

# Get the full chat info
chat = await app.invoke(
    raw.functions.channels.get_full_channel.GetFullChannel(channel=peer)
)

# Access the slow mode value
if chat.full_chat.slowmode_enabled:
    print(chat.full_chat.slowmode_seconds)

The chat.full_chat.slowmode_seconds will give you the slow mode wait time in seconds. Handle your case accordingly.

Solution 2
This will probably be a straight forward solution. Just try to send the message. When the SlowmodeWait error occurs you'll retrieve the wait time value from the exception and you'll just retry after the delay.
try:
    # Your existing send method calls here...
    await app.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text="Hello World")

except errors.exceptions.flood_420.SlowmodeWait as e:
    print(e.value) # this will be the number of seconds you need to wait

Hope this helps :)

Btw, don't be confused to see the term channel in the first solution. In MTProto, supergroups are kind of treated as similar to channels. You'll get to kno wthis in the messages.ChatFull docs

Thank you very much! I totally forgot about the possibility of invoking get_full_chat! That was incredibly helpful. @thecosmicintrovertdude

I am fairly new to this platform and don't know if this is the right place to ask, but do you know any useful Telegram auto forwarders for userbots that take this into account? (Periodically forwarding a message into several mega groups/chats and checking the waiting time?) You seem to be very experienced. Also televerse is very interesting! :)

Thanks for the words, @Unthought. Unfortunately, I haven't talked with enough user bots to answer that . Usually when I have an issue that can be solved with user bot, I'd just build one for myself, and leave the spot right after getting my job done. So, unfortunately, I don't have any suggestions for now. Sorry :)
